# Oracle SQL find project with most hours logged multiple entries for hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get my query to return the project that has the most hours and the name of that project. I have a query that works for the single largest entry, but I want it to add up the hours if there are more than one entry for that particular project. I know I'm going to have to use a sum and group by pnum, but I can't figure out the specifics it keeps telling me not a group by expression everyway I have tried it.

Here is the code to grab it without adding it up

```
`SELECT p.pnum, p.pname from workers_hours wh , projects p WHERE wh.hours = (SELECT MAX(hours) as M_Hours FROM workers_hours) AND p.pnum=wh.pnum;`
```

Here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE projects  (pname varchar(255), pnum int PRIMARY KEY, plocation varchar(255))
INSERT INTO projects VALUES(‘Earth Shattering Kaboom’, 101, ‘Mars’)
INSERT INTO projects VALUES('Find Missing Link', 102, 'Bigfoot Woods');
INSERT INTO projects VALUES('Let the Galaxy Burn', 103, 'Abaddons Flagship');
INSERT INTO projects VALUES('Better Lunches', 104, 'Lunch Room');

CREATE TABLE workers_hours (entry int PRIMARY KEY, wnum int, hours int, pnum int)
INSERT INTO workers_hours VALUES (1, 111, 20, 101)
INSERT INTO workers_hours VALUES (1, 166, 80, 103)
INSERT INTO workers_hours VALUES (3, 102, 40, 103)
INSERT INTO workers_hours VALUES (4, 101, 120, 102)
INSERT INTO workers_hours VALUES (5, 102, 40, 104)
```

Solution:

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT p.pname, sum(wh.hours) as sum_hours
from projects p 
join workers_hours wh on p.pnum = wh.pnum
group by p.pname
ORDER BY sum(wh.hours) desc)  WHERE rownum<=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a list order by the sum of hours for every project

```
SELECT p.pname, sum(wh.hours) as sum_hours
from projects p 
join workers_hours wh on p.pnum = wh.pnum
group by p.pname  
order by sum(wh.hours) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for some reason i had not thought of splitting it off into its own select and then just truncating the rows with another. I was trying to do it all with one select.

Comment: @SteveShields did you intend to comment on my answer? This query does not use a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from projects
 where pnum = (select pnum
                 from (select pnum, sum(hours) as sum_hrs
                         from workers_hours
                        group by pnum
                        order by 2 desc)
                where rownum = 1)
```

See fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ccbf/4/0

Comment: No i had used his query as a subquery to solve my problem before you responded. Thank you for the help though that is a good website